# Java System Independent Root Directory Paths

Tags: java

In a Windows system my path would be like this:

```
C:/example/
```

And in a Linux system my path would be like this:

```
/example/
```

Is there some utility function to have a single string work in both systems?

Answer (score 2):

Windows will accept forward slashes as directory separators, and adds the current drive, which defaults to the system drive, which is usually `C:`. So the path `/example/` is usually equivalent to `C:\example\` on Windows and is cross platform.

Usually, however, the base of a full absolute path will be different on the two platforms, so you can't just hard-code an absolute path like this.  You will most often come up with the base of a path in some way that produces something unique to the platform, and you will then use a Unix-style relative path to indicate traversal from there.  An example of this is the current user's home directory.  If you know that the `data` directory exists in the current user's home, then you can use this cross platform code:

String path = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/data"

There are other ways to get the base path to which you will add a Unix-style relative path.  The base path will often come either from a configuration file or from some Java Standard Library call, similar to the use of `getProperty()` above.  And like the above example, it is common to then add a Unix-style relative path to that base path to specify the location of the directory or file you're interested in.

Comment: Java does not convert Unix-style paths to Windows paths and does not default the drive letter. Windows, on the other hand, accepts `/` as a directory separator (and has since MSDOS 2.0) and has a concept of the current drive which will be used if a path doesn't contain a drive letter.

Comment: Ah. My bad.  I've been programming for Windows compatibility lately, and had the incorrect assumption that it was Java and not Windows that was conforming the Unix-style paths.  I didn't think enough about the WHY for the behavior I rely on.  Makes sense that Java wouldn't be modifying them when you think about it.  Thanks for comment.  I changed my answer.  I hope it's correct now.

Comment: "user.home" is equivalent to `~` directory though, not `/` root.

Comment: I wasn't saying that.  In fact, I said "If you know that the data directory exists in the current user's home".  But you point out another problem, which I think is confusing.  I was using "root" when I should be saying "base".  I fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Windows, you can always refer the path in the following manner and it works.

> C:\example\data

In case of Linux or Unix, you can refer the path in the following manner

> /home/example/data

If you want to access in a platform independent manner, you should use **File.separator** in case \ or / .

However, it is always recommended to use the following to access the user directory.

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.home");
```

It will give you the path in all operating system.